# draw image with opacity on to a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I've got an image. I use `drawImage()` to draw it on to a canvas.

My question is: If the image has an opacity of 0.4, how do I draw it in the same opacity on to the canvas.

I've created a sample [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0qz7f131/1/). How can I draw `#scream` on to `mycanvas` maintaining 0.4 opacity on the image.

html:

```
<p>Image with 0.4 opacity to be used:</p>
<img id="scream" width="200" height="200" src="http://img42.com/NMMU8+">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="220" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
```

css:

```
#scream{
    opacity: 0.4;
}
#myCanvas{
    background-color: #f60;
}
```

js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: You can do so using `ctx.globalAlpha`, see the possible duplicate question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `globalAlpha` but make sure that you set it before drawing the image:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
```

Comment: how can i add in only one ctx?

Comment: @NarendraSolanki If I'm understanding your comment correctly, you could use `save()` and `restore()` before and after respectively to avoid making everything you draw afterwards use the same alpha value set here.

Comment: sweet mother of midnight, I never knew you could do this!  It saves so much headache with style isolation containers upon containers and overlapping canvasi... I should really read the docs next time XD